# Adding a picture to the right of a table

Tags: graphics, positioning

Hello I am currently writing a CV and trying to include a picture of myself to the right of a table that shows personal information. However no matter what commands I try I cannot add to the right of the table. Here is the code:

```
\section{Personal Data}

\begin{tabular}{rl}
    \textsc{Place and Date of Birth:} & Someplace, Italy  | dd Month 1912 \\
    \textsc{Address:}   & CV Inn 19, 20301, Milano, Italy \\
    \textsc{Phone:}     & +39 123 456789\\
    \textsc{email:}     & \href{mailto:alessandro.plasmati@gmail.com}{alessandro.plasmati@gmail.com}
\end{tabular}
```

Whenever I try to include `\includegraphics[scale=0.10]{picture.jpg}` it simply brakes the table in the middle. I also tried `\hbox{\hspace{2.5cm}\includegraphics[scale=0.10]{picture.jpg}}` This will add the picture at approx. the right position to the right but the table is still broken in the middle. My question is then what code should i write to add a picture perfectly to the right of a table and should I include it in the `table` environment or outside the environment?

Thanks for all answers!

Comment: What code did you write exactly for this inclusion?

Comment: What `\documentclass` are you using to write your CV?

Comment: You should include the graphic after \end{tabular} with no blank line (you might throw in a \hfill)..  Also use the [b] option for the tabular to align bottoms.

Comment: sorry about not including it, Im pretty new to latex. I am using the following class:
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

Comment: what does "breaks the table in the middle" mean? a `tabular` is an unbreakable box. the tabular and the graphic will be positioned just as letters are positioned, `XY` will make them come side by side `X Y` makes them have a space between and `X <blank line> Y` makes them come one above the other.

Answer (score 2):

You can include it inside or outside of the table as long as there's room for it on the sale line. Note the *bottom* of the picture will aligned with  the first line of the table, so we have to use `\raisebox` command  in order to align tops.

Here is a simple code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[osfI]{garamondx}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{Personal Data}

\begin{tabular}[t]{rl}
  \textsc{Place and Date of Birth:} & Milano, Italy | dd Month 1473                                              \\
  \textsc{Address:}                 & Palazzo Carmagnola, Milano, Italy                                          \\
  \textsc{Phone:}                   & +39 123 456789                                                             \\
  \textsc{email:}                   & \href{mailto:alessandro.plasmati@gmail.com}{alessandro.plasmati@gmail.com}
\end{tabular}
\quad
\raisebox{\dimexpr0.7\baselineskip-\height}{\includegraphics[scale=0.35]{hermine}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'd set the entire construction inside a [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) of width `\linewidth` and a single `X`-column (the middle column, since it contains the most data). That will allow the table to stretch out as needed in that column. The image column (far right), will only contain an image in the first row which is lowered into position using `\raisebox{.}[0pt][0pt]{<image>}`. Using `[0pt][0pt]` ensures that the image depth/height is removed after moving, otherwise it will increase the row height/depth:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx,tabularx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{Personal Data}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ @{} >{\scshape}r X l @{} }
  Place and Date of Birth: & Randomville, Random $\vert$ DD MMM YYYY    &
    \raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+.7\normalbaselineskip}[0pt][0pt]
      {\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=4\normalbaselineskip]{example-image}} \\
  Address:                 & Randombille, Random                        \\
  Phone:                   & +1-234-567-8901                            \\
  email:                   & \href{mailto:who@cares.com}{who@cares.com}
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

I specified a fixed width and height for the image, which might not be necessary in your case. This depends on the image you use, of course.